# post json data in jquery, consume in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Like to know how to post json form data from javascript on submit button and receive the json data at node js server.

Here is what i tried. it just print '{} ' on node.js server terminal

jquery function to POST json data

```
function onSubmit() {

           $.post("/SaveData", FormDataJson, function(data) {

         }, "json");

 return true;
}
```

node js router function to received data

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
var dcuJsonEncoder = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/SaveData', dcuJsonEncoder, function(request, response){
     var deviceConfigObj = JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 4);

    console.log(deviceConfigObj);
    response.send(deviceConfigObj);    // echo the result back
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dcuJsonEncoder = bodyParser.json();
var urlEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

app.post(
    '/SaveData',
    dcuJsonEncoder,
    urlEncoded,
    function(request, response){
        var deviceConfigObj = JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 4);
        console.log(deviceConfigObj);
        response.json(deviceConfigObj);    // echo the result back
    }
);
```

Comment: console.log is working. response.json() is not working.  I tried to trigger a  web page, like response.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "SecondPage" ); app.get('/SecondPage', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "SecondPage.htm" );
})  But not working

Comment: What does response.json() do?

Comment: This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify(). http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json

So, the problem probably is that you're using JSON.stringify() and then this method also uses it. Try response.json(request.body)...